# Multiple CNAME pointing to Openshift application

Tags: dns, openshift, cname

I have two domains that I have pointed to my Openshift v2 application, and have also set up as aliases. The first one is working fine, but the second receives infinite 301 redirects to itself.

What could be causing this?